# How can I add another permission to in pairs in Lua for receiving calls simultaneously?

Tags: lua, fivem

```
elseif Message[1] == "policia" then
    local Keyboard = vKEYBOARD.keySingle(source,"policia:")
    local d,policia = vRP.NumPermission("Police")
    for Passport,Sources4 in pairs(d) do
        if Keyboard then 
            async(function()
                vRPC.PlaySound(Sources4,"ATM_WINDOW","HUD_FRONTEND_DEFAULT_SOUNDSET")
                TriggerClientEvent("NotifyPush",Sources4,{ phone = vRP.Identity(Passportss).phone, name = vRP.Identity(Passportss)["name"].." "..vRP.Identity(Passportss)["name2"].."  "..vRP.Identity(Passport).phone, title = Keyboard[1], x = coords["x"], y = coords["y"], z = coords["z"], criminal = "Policia", time = "Recebido às "..os.date("%H:%M"), blipColor = 16 })
                return true
            end)
        end
    end
```

I need one more permission to receive the signal simultaneously, ie the `vRP.NumPermission("Police")` will receive the call and I want to add the `vRP.NumPermission("PCSP")` to receive the same call, how to do it